# Touch event on blended layer image Android

Tags: android, blend

I have a precut image i.e One base image and multiple transparent layer of the the base image.
I am trying to add the layer image on top of base image to select the layer and apply different color on it.

I have tried the following way to achieve it but not able to finish.

1. ImageView - I am overlapping imageview with transparent layer image. It shows the blended image but the touch event detects the finally overlapped image id always. Because I draw the image with fill parent, all the layer image is also the same
2. Layer Drawable - It can allow only drawable images, but my use case is to load the precut from gallery or other resource. Even I can't select layer on touch.
3. GPUImage library - The image is not showing full imageview.

Regards
Sathiya

Answer (score 0):

Extend the View class, make the onDraw() function draw what you want to draw. The onTouchEvent() function implement the touch events. What you're trying to do isn't subsumed in any view already made but it's pretty easy to make a view. Just draw the bitmaps on the canvas in the correct order with the correct paints with the right transparency.

```
    @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
int numLayers = mLayers.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < numLayers; i++) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.concat(matrix);
            //or
            canvas.translate(rect.left,rect.top);
            Bitmap b = mLayers.get(i);
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, paint);
            canvas.restore();
        }}
```

You end up doing this a bunch just adding bitmaps to the canvas in whatever places and order as needed.

Comment: Can you share some sample code. I have tried LayeredImageView but I couldn't get the dynamic imageview id.

Comment: It's simply the code to draw a bitmap applied several times. You could loop it or just apply a set number of them. Just apply that stuff to the canvas. canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, paint) and do it for each of the relevant bitmaps in the relevant places.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
        if (matrix != null) {
            int numLayers = mLayers.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < numLayers; i++) {
                Bitmap b = mLayers.get(i);
                canvas.drawBitmap(b, matrix, null);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I have tried the above code to draw , but on touch how to detect which image I have clicked.

Comment: If you want the position adjusted for each bitmap you need to store the rectangle bounds for them and adjust their position appropriately. Then when you do the on touch. Cycle through the rectangles checking the rect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY()) for each of them and when true, you have a hit.

Comment: rectangle bounds covers whole screen. It will give the result of finally image drawn result.

Comment: I have base image with layered transparent image of same size. If I adjust the position.

Comment: I couldn't post my code and screenshot for reference

Comment: If they are truly overlapped you clicked on both of them. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I couldn't post image and code for your reference, Is it possible to mail you regarding the same?